# Unable to display horizontal submenu with vertical menu using background img

Tags: html, css

I am working on some website project and i am trying to create a vertical menu which displays  a horizontal submenu as background image assign to ul element on hover event but that image stick at one location and not displaying as per hover event on other menu element.I want to display it as per horizontally to its main menu item.

**Here are my HTML code:**

```
    <nav class="side_menu">
    <ul id="side_menu">
      <li><a href="#!/page_splash"><span></span><span></span><strong></strong><strong></strong></a></li>
      <li><a href="#!/page_home"><span>Home</span><span>welcome note</span><strong></strong><strong></strong></a></li>
      <li class="with_ul"><a href="#!/page_about"><span>About</span><span>company info</span><strong></strong><strong></strong></a>
           <ul class="side_submenu_1">
               <li><a href="#!/page_more">company</a></li>
               <li><a href="#!/page_more">team</a></li>
               <li><a href="#!/page_more">news</a></li>
               <li><a href="#!/page_more">projects</a></li>
           </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="with_ul"><a href="#!/page_folio"><span>Rent</span><span>Latest Offers</span><strong></strong><strong></strong></a>
          <ul class="side_submenu_1">
               <li><a href="#!/page_more">FOLIO</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!/page_sale"><span>Sell</span><span>contact us!</span><strong></strong><strong></strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/page_services"><span>services</span><span>what we do?</span><strong></strong><strong></strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/page_mail"><span>contacts</span><span>contact us!</span><strong></strong><strong></strong></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.side_menu{
  position: relative; 
  display: block; 
  float: left; 
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
 }

#side_menu>li{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}

#side_menu>li:first-child{
  display:none;
 }

#side_menu>li>a{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  float:left;width:103px;
  height:102px;
  margin-top: -2.5px;
 }

#side_menu>li>a>span{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  font:24px/1.2em 'Contrail One',sans-serif;
  color:#fff;
  display:block;
  padding-top:28px;
  margin-left:15px;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  z-index:2;
 }

#side_menu>li>a>span:first-child+span{
  font-size:10px;
  color:rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  padding:0px;
  margin-top:-5px;
  letter-spacing:0;
 }

#side_menu>li:first-child>a>strong{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
 }

#side_menu>li:first-child+li>a>span+span+strong{
   background:url(http://edplace.com/userfiles/image/circle.gif) center no-repeat;
 }

#side_menu>li:first-child+li+li>a>span+span+strong{
   background:url(http://edplace.com/userfiles/image/circle.gif) center no-repeat;
 }

#side_menu>li:first-child+li+li+li>a>span+span+strong{
   background:url(http://edplace.com/userfiles/image/circle.gif) center no-repeat;
 }

#side_menu>li:first-child+li+li+li+li>a>span+span+strong{
   background:url(http://edplace.com/userfiles/image/circle.gif) center no-repeat;
 }

#side_menu>li:first-child+li+li+li+li+li>a>span+span+strong{
   background:url(http://edplace.com/userfiles/image/circle.gif) center no-repeat;
 }

#side_menu>li:first-child+li+li+li+li+li+li>a>span+span+strong{
   background:url(http://edplace.com/userfiles/image/circle.gif) center no-repeat;
 }

#side_menu>li>a>strong{
   display:inline-block;
   position:absolute;
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   z-index:0;
 }

 #side_menu>li>a>span+span+strong+strong{
     background:url(../images/side_menu_bg_def.png) center no-repeat;
  }

   .side_submenu_1{
      display: none; 
      position: absolute;
      left: 50px;
      top: 0;
      width:103px;
      height:102px;
      background:url(http://www.drewmichaelblake.com/r/i/YellowCircle.png) center no-      repeat;
   }

  .side_submenu_1 li{
       position:relative;
       display:block;
       margin-bottom:4px;
   }

  .side_submenu_1 li:first-child{
       padding-top:18px;
   }

  .side_submenu_1 a{
       position:relative;
       display:block;
       font:11px/1.2em 'Contrail One',sans-serif;
       color:#615f5e;
   }

  #side_menu > li:hover .side_submenu_1{
       display:inline-block;
   }
```

I tried but unable to display submenu in front of its main menu item....I added submenu for About and Rent Tab only. Here is the current demo http://codepen.io/abdulwahid24/pen/Eiwkr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem is that your top level LIs have no height, because they are not wrapping around their floated contents. An easy fix for that is to change this:

```
#side_menu>li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

to this:

```
#side_menu>li {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Even i tried according to you but also it not working submenu top remains constant which is not required. Would you please solve it in JSfiddle or Codepen.

Comment: Ohh Thts working for me.. actually i was doing for .side_menu that why mine was not working...Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is absolute positioning.  Adjusting the top and left values on your sub-menu styling will help you place them as you want them.  For example, modifying this rule positions the sub-menu roughly where you want it.  Note that I modified `left:` and `top:` to be 100px;

In your situation, the left value should always remain the same, the top value will change depending how far down the page the submenu is supposed to sit.

```
.side_submenu_1{
  display: none; 
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  width:103px;
  height:102px;
 background:url(http://www.drewmichaelblake.com/r/i/YellowCircle.png) center no-repeat;}
```

Comment: Its not working. I changed top and left value to 100px but top should be changed according to menu selection.